# How does the identifier resolution work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain how identifier resolution works for Javascript  taking the following scenarios :

1. A global function is called .
2. A function inside an user defined javascript object is called .

Comment: The definitive reference is [ECMA-262 section 10](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10), there is an authoritative article on the comp.lang.javascript FAQ on closures that explains [Identifier Resolution, Execution Contexts and scope chains](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc) in detail. That article was written for ECMA-262 ed 3, the recent ES5 is essentially identical though the terminology has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn the context and scoping in ECMA Script to understand this. And in between is it identifier or variable?

Identifiers are normally tagged to window object. Say String() it's actually window.String().

Normally when a  page loads the all the variables and functions are added as properties to the window object. The window object becomes the global context(GC) in the case of browsers. So when a global function(this is just a method nothing is there like a global function) is called the variable is just looked in the global context. And thus it'll identify the variable.

But if there is a function inside which an inner function is there then identifying a global variable will be two folds first it'll check in function scope and then in global scope. If the variable is a function variable. Then the variable will always be there in the functions execution context(EC)